# ElasticSearch document script sorting

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch

I've a query that return a score NULL.

```json
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "sort": {
    "_script": {
      "script": "doc['price'].value * doc['sales.quarter'].value",
      "type": "number",
      "order": "desc"
    }
  },
  "size": 15,
  "from": 0
}
```

I want to get 15th best sales and this query returns a _score equals to NULL

Do you know why this happen ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found a solution:
Custom score query !

```
{
  "query": {
    "custom_score": {
      "query": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "script": "doc['sales.quarter'].value * doc['price'].value"
    }
  },
  "size": 15,
  "from": 0
}
```

Comment: argh, gimme another solution, i got same problem dude :(